# Building maven project causes error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Hi I am building my project using MAVEN , my project structure is like this.

```
core
  core-contact
     address
     phone
  core - itinerary
```

a piece of code of each modules pom.xml file is as follows

**core : pom.xml**

```
      <groupId>ginfo.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>core</artifactId>
      <name>${productBrand} - Core POM</name>
      <packaging>pom</packaging>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <modules>
         <module>Contact</module>
         <module>Itinerary</module>
      </modules>
```

**address : pom.xml**

```
       <parent>
           <groupId>ginfo.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>core-contact</artifactId>
           <version>1.1</version>
           <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
        </parent>
           <artifactId>core-address</artifactId>
           <name>${productBrand} - core-address</name>
           <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

**phone : pom.xml**

```
          <parent>
             <groupId>ginfo.core</groupId>
             <artifactId>core-contact</artifactId>
             <version>1.1</version>
             <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
          </parent>

       <artifactId>core-phone</artifactId>
       <name>${productBrand} - core-phone</name>
       <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

**core-itinerary : pom.xml**

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>ginfo.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
     </parent>
     <artifactId>core-itinerary</artifactId>
     <name>${productBrand} - core-itinerary</name>
     <packaging>jar</packaging>

     <description>
       ${productBrand} - core-itinerary
     </description>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>ginfo.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>core-contact</artifactId>
         <version>1.1</version>
       </dependency>
```

**core-contact : pom.xml**

```
      <parent>
        <groupId>ginfo.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
      </parent>

     <artifactId>core-contact</artifactId>
     <name>${productBrand} - core-contact</name>
     <packaging>pom</packaging>

     <description>
       ${productBrand} - core-contact
     </description>
     <modules>
        <module>Address</module>
        <module>Phone</module>
     </modules>
```

When I am trying to build core-itinerary using **mvn clean install**  I am getting the following error :

`Failed to execute goal on project core-itinerary: could not resolve dependancies for project  ginfo.core : core-itinerary: jar 1.1: could not find artifact ginfo.core : core-contact.jar : 1.1  in mvnrepository (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)`

please help me as how to resolve this issue

Comment: `address` and `phone` are referencing `core-contact` as their parent - where's pom for that one?

Comment: Please use the edit link and add that to your question rather than comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple, please run:

```
mvn clean install
```

from the top parent project (it is named `core` in your example).

The reason behind your error: `could not resolve dependencies` was lack of the dependent module being built/ installed first. And mentioned above solution, will build & install needed modules in a proper order.

---

**EDIT:** Ahh I see,
your `core-contact` uses POM packaging (`<packaging>pom</packaging>`), but inside `core-itinerary/pom.xml` you have a following dependency:

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>ginfo.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>core-contact</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

Because above entry hasn't specified `<type>pom</type>`, so maven assumes it is `<type>jar</type>` (default value) which of course doesn't reflect the reality.
To make it work please change to:

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>ginfo.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>core-contact</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
   <type>pom</type>      <!-- crucial line -->
 </dependency>
```

Comment: I run "mvn clean install"  at "core" but getting the following error :  Failed to execute goal on project core-itinerary : could not resolve dependencies  for the project  ginfo.core :  core-itinerary:jar :1.1; failure to find ginfo.core: core-contact: jar : 1.1 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository  resolution will not be  reattempted  until the update interval  of mvnrepository  has elapsed or updated are forced

Comment: the core-1.1 is not installed properly.. make sure it is present in .m2/repository/path_to_your_core_jar/<jarfile>... ( assuming ur maven repo is in the default path)

Comment: Great answer .   Thank You very much.    adding the line <type>pom</type> worked very well.    Struggled for a lot of time to resolve this.